# could not initialize proxy - no Session, why update works and merge doesn't?

Tags: java, hibernate

I got "could not initialize proxy - no Session" while trying to get a lazy loaded object. I got to know that is because my object is detached and I need to update it first.
My question is why this works:

```
repo.update(object);
object.getSomeList();
```

when those doesn't:

```
object = repo.merge(object);
object.getSomeList();

repo.evict(object);
repo.get(objectClass,object.primaryKey());
object.getSomeList();
```

Repo is my repository class that has reference to Session and runs session.saveOrUpdate(...), session.merge(...) etc

I thought all versions let me get a persistent object, so it's not detached any more. Is that true? If yes, while I get no Session error? If no, why no? :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you should initialize Lazy properties

```
Hibernate.initialize(object.getSomeList());
```